# How to solve an Error while sending a structure containing an array using ZeroMQ in C++

Tags: c++, zeromq

A client sends a structure ( containing an array ) to a server ten times. Servers job is to receive this structure and to print it. But it receives the structure only once and prints it and exits giving this error
"`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'zmq::error_t'`".

This is the client C++ code:

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <zmq2.h>
#include "structure.h"

int main (void)
{
    int flags=0,value,buffer[10];
    printf ("Connecting to hello world server…\n");
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
    void *requester = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);
    zmq_connect (requester, "tcp://localhost:5555");


    for(int i=0;i!=10;i++)
    {
        msg.arr[i]=i;   
    }

    for(int i=0;i!=10;i++)
    {
        printf ("Sending Hello %d…\n", i);
        zmq_send(requester,&msg, sizeof(Message),0);
    }
    zmq_close (requester);
    zmq_ctx_destroy (context);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the server C++ code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "structure.h"
#include "zmq.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main () {
    int val;
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
    socket.bind ("tcp://*:5555");
    while(true)
    {
        Message* msg;   
        zmq::message_t zmsg;
        socket.recv(&zmsg);
        msg = (Message*)zmsg.data();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            std::cout<<msg->arr[i]<<std::endl;  
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the **`structure.h`**

```
struct Message
{
  int arr[10];
}msg;
```

How do I receive all ten structures from server side and print that ten structures received?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the message inside the exception that was thrown?  You might want to catch and print it.

Comment: This was the exception- "Caught exception "Operation cannot be accomplished in current state" "@John Zwinck

Comment: Since you say you get an exception I assume it's the C++ server program that crashes? Have you tried running in a debugger to see *where* it happens? What part throws the exception? I also recommend you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Look at type of your sockets ZMQ_REQ, ZMQ_REP, and read documentation http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-socket - `This socket type allows only an alternating sequence of zmq_send(request) and subsequent zmq_recv(reply) calls`. You cannot call 10 times zmq_send as you did it. After sending message you should wait to get reponse. Then you can send message again.

Comment: Thank you so much@rafix07. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Better use a PUSH/PULL of an XREQ/XREP,
<sub>as the original REP/REQ enforces a strict chain of .send()-.recv()-.send()-.recv()- ...</sub>

If your needs are exactly as expressed above, a just a change of the ZeroMQ Scalable Formal Communication Archetype pattern is enough.

If you opt to keep as close as possible to the `REQ/REP` "similarity", use **`XREQ/XREP`**, if having more to say and planning for some further extending the distributed signalling/messaging services infrastructure, better use a tandem of single-direction hoses `C->S` + `S->C` using a pair of **`PUSH/PULL`** + **`PUSH/PULL`**.

A **`PAIR/PAIR`** might be an option if a messaging paradigm can live with just one, exclusive, pair of nodes, where `PAIR/PAIR` ( as implemented ) does not provide a way to later expand to `.connect()` into `N:1` or `1:M` or `N:M` peer-nodes framework.